Esav's religious and Jewish status
Is Esav still considered a Jew considering his parents being Yitzchak and Rivka, and having brit milah? Also, what was his religious status? Was he really an idol worshipper or just non-observant, perhaps even an atheist? Please cite sources, thanks.

"Is Esav still considered a Jew considering his parents being Yitzchak and Rivka, and having brit milah?" Why would Esav's parents being Yitzchak and Rivka, and him having had brit milah, make him a Jew?

@TamirEvan why would it not?

@ddas916100 Most people, even at the time Esav lived, were not Jews. By that default, he was not a Jew. How does his parents being Yitzchak and Rivka, and him having had a brit milah, change that?

@TamirEvan so Yitzchak and Rivka weren't Jews? Also, brit milah was a ritual largely exclusive to the Jews at that time to signify that they were Jewish, no? Of course, Avraham's male workers were also circumcised but they didn't exactly descend from a Jewish mother, whereas Esav did (unless I'm missing something)

@ddas91600 I think Tamir is trying to get you to answer the more fundamental question first - what imparts Jewishness. Then this ancilliary question will either be answered or fall away.

I remember seeing an Ohr Hachaim that says that the Shechina rests more on Esav than on Ishmael due to the fact the Esav is a true son of Itzchak as opposed to Ishmael who was born from a concubine.
(I would be much obliged if anyone knows the source for this.) This would seem to imply that Esav is part of the clan so to speak.

https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.18a.2?lang=bi&with=all

@ddas91600 "so Yitzchak and Rivka weren't Jews?" In what way were they Jews? Even if you're assuming descent from Avraham makes one a Jew: (a) You should be explicit about it in the question (preferably along with why you think so). (b) How was Rivka a Jew? "Also, brit milah was a ritual largely exclusive to the Jews at that time to signify that they were Jewish, no?" Doesn't Avraham's male workers being circumcised negate this?

@ddas91600 "Of course, Avraham's male workers were also circumcised but they didn't exactly descend from a Jewish mother, whereas Esav did (unless I'm missing something)" Wouldn't Esav descending from a Jewish mother automatically make him a Jew, even without circumcision?

@TamirEvan I automatically assumed that since Yitzchak and Rivka are one of the patriarchs and matriarchs of the Jewish people, then they must be Jews. So yes, Esav would still be a Jew sans circumcision.

@ddas91600 "I automatically assumed that since Yitzchak and Rivka are one of the patriarchs and matriarchs of the Jewish people, then they must be Jews." If being one of the patriarchs and matriarchs of the Jewish people is what makes them Jews, then wouldn't it follow that Esav not being one of the patriarchs and matriarchs (especially when Yaakov and his wives are), means that he is not a Jew?

@TamirEvan sure, but does him not being a patriarch make him a non-Jew even though he comes from parents who are Jews?

The commentary Tosafos Daas Zekeinim on Bereshis 25:25 quotes a midrash without a reference, from which we can answer negatively about Eisav's circumcision:

ויצא הראשון אדמוני, “the first baby emerged, reddish looking;” according to a Midrash, when his father saw that, he concluded that the blood of the infant had not yet matured to the stage when he could be circumcised without that operation endangering his life, and that is why he delayed the date for the circumcision. Something similar is related in the Talmud, tractate Shabbat, folio 134, where Rabbi Nathan relates that he once met a lady who had lost two of her children as a result of circumcision. She asked him if she had to circumcise her third son also and risk losing him too. When Rabbi Nathan looked at the infant, he noted that his skin looked extremely red. He therefore told his mother to wait with circumcising him until this red skin would become normal looking. She did so, and circumcised him in due course and he survived without further problem. When Yitzchok waited a year or two for the skin colour of Esau to change and it did not happen, he assumed that this son was going to remain in that condition, but he still did not circumcise him. When he turned 13, he still restrained himself from circumcising him. He had waited all this time thinking that seeing he had not been circumcised at the age of eight days he would circumcise him at the age Yishmael had been circumcised. This is what was meant in the Book of Ezekiel chapter 35,6: אם לא דם שנאת ודם ירדפך, “surely though you have hated blood, blood shall pursue you.”

At the same time, the midrash Bereshis Rabba 76:9 states in affirmative that Eisav was circumcised:

“He arose during that night and he took his two wives, and his two maidservants, and his eleven children, and crossed the ford of the Yabok” (Genesis 32:23).
“He arose during that night and he took his two wives, and his two maidservants…” – but where was Dina? He placed her in a chest and locked it with her in it. He said: ‘This wicked one has a covetous eye; [I do this] so he will not direct his eyes, see her, and take her from me.’
Rav Huna said in the name of Rabbi Abba HaKohen Bardela: The Holy One blessed be He said to him: ‘“For the sake of one who deprives his neighbor of kindness” (Job 6:14) – you withheld kindness from your neighbor, you withheld kindness from your brother. Had she married the man, she would not have engaged in licentiousness.  You did not seek to marry her to a circumcised man, so she married an uncircumcised man. You did not seek to marry her in a permitted fashion, so she married in a prohibited fashion.’ That is what is written: “Dina daughter of Leah…went out” (Genesis 34:1).

This is resolved with the help of the commentary Yefeh Toar on Bereshis Rabba 76.9.3. The full published version by Machon Aharon states (unlike Sefaria):

We have a difficulty, above in p. 63:18 Eisav hates the blood of milla, i.e. consequently he was ערל (uncircumcized), and we cannot apply there principle that ערלי/uncircumcized of Israel are called מהולים/circumcized (as in mishna Nedarim 3:11), thus what we explained there - is fitting.

By Sefaria numbering, the reference is midrash Bereshis Rabba 63:13 (Sefaria uses different enumeration as compared to the edition of the midrash). The relevant words there:

Did Esau hate blood? Rabbi Shmuel bar Naḥman said: This is the blood of birthright and offerings. Rabbi Levi said: זה דם מילה - This is the blood of circumcision. The Rabbis said: You hated a person’s blood in his body. That is what is written: “He loved curses, and they will now come upon him. [He had no desire for blessing, and it will now be far from him]” (Psalms 109:17).

Explans Yefeh Toar (in the Machon Aharon edition):

זה דם מילה: he pulled his orla, and all his children were uncircumcized.

As far as person's religious status, in Judaism either a person believes in G-d, or is a follower of Avodah Zara (foreign worship - anything but G-d). There is no distinction for atheism.
